# How to configure WebStorm debugger to work with my Express app

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, webstorm, pm2

I'm trying to debug a Node Express application with the WebStorm debugger

The thing is that the WebStorm debugger doesn't hit the breakpoint although I think it set up correctly.

I run my application by:

```
node --inspect server.js
```

and then the server is up, accepting requests, it logged:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/5790aa86-c46c-48bc-998c-e014244440b7
```

(I've also tried: "node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229" server.js which didn't worked)

My WebStorm debugger config is:

```
Node.js Remote Debug
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 9229
```

---

Node version is: v8.11.4

WebStorm version: WebStorm 2016.3.4

---

Eventually I want to run it with pm2, so an answer which will guide me how to set the process.yml would be great. I've tried to put in the node_args `['--inspect']` but the same results, it did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Node.js Remote** run configuration can only be used when debugging with TCP-based Protocol (`Node.js < 7.x`).

To remotely debug application with Chrome Debugging Protocol (with `--inspect`/`--inspect-brk`), you need using **Chromium Remote** run configuration

- run your app with node `--inspect-brk=<my custom port here> index.js`
- create a **Chromium Remote** run configuration, specify your custom port as a **Port:** there, press **Debug**

Note: these instructions refer to WebStorm < 2018.x. With recent WebStorm releases, you need using  **Attach to Node.js/Chrome** configuration for attaching to a running process